# WSDL Role at producer side?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am new to webservices. I know wsdl is used to generate consumer side stubs to send the request to producer.
My question is does producer also uses the WSDL file in any way to map the the incoming message to sorresponding
service implementation class ?

May be producer does not use the WSDL instead skelton is created when service is published and prodeucer use this
sketon to map the incoming request to right service implemtation?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely right..

Producer generate the wsdl and store it somewhere so that it can be provided to consumer to understand the request and response message structure along with the protocol, operations and service location.

Webservice implementation frameworks like cxf etc. already know How they are going to receive message from consumer, which operation they are going to call. They simply marshal and unmarshal incoming request and outgoing response. They don't use wsdl.

In my opinion.
Correct me experts if i am wrong...

Comment: My question is how producer knows which service it has to call on receiving the request? Does it use WSDL here?